# Superimpose lights with shaders in LibGDX game

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader, light

I'm making a turn-based game with Libgdx.

I'm trying to create a fog of war for battles by adding a mask on the map and a maplight on each cell in the fight zone.

To do this I have to superimpose lights, but I can't.

The result in game :

[image]

The java render code :

```
//draw the light to the FBO
fbo.begin();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
batch.setShader(defaultShader);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batch.begin();
float lightSize = lightOscillate? (4.75f + 0.25f * (float)Math.sin(zAngle) + .2f*MathUtils.random()):5.0f;
//Draw light 1
batch.draw(light, 0, 0, lightSize, lightSize);

//Draw light 2
batch.draw(light, 2, 2, lightSize, lightSize);

batch.end();
fbo.end();

//draw the actual scene
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
batch.setShader(finalShader);
batch.begin();
fbo.getColorBufferTexture().bind(1); //this is important! bind the FBO to the 2nd texture unit
light.bind(0); //we force the binding of a texture on first texture unit to avoid artefacts
            //this is because our default and ambiant shader dont use multi texturing...
            //youc can basically bind anything, it doesnt matter
tilemap.render(batch, dt);
batch.end();
```

The fragment shader code :

```
varying LOWP vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

//texture samplers
uniform sampler2D u_texture; //diffuse map
uniform sampler2D u_lightmap;   //light map

//additional parameters for the shader
uniform vec2 resolution; //resolution of screen
uniform LOWP vec4 ambientColor; //ambient RGB, alpha channel is intensity 

void main() {
   vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);
   vec2 lighCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
   vec4 light = texture2D(u_lightmap, lighCoord);

   vec3 ambient = ambientColor.rgb * ambientColor.a;
   vec3 intensity = ambient + light.rgb;
    vec3 finalColor = diffuseColor.rgb * intensity;

   gl_FragColor = vColor * light; //vec4(finalColor, diffuseColor.a);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to enable alpha blending.

Comment: I tried to add `Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
  Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` after batch.begin() and in create() method but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The alpha blending had to be enabled.

Here the correct render code :

```
public void render() {
    final float dt = Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);

    //draw the light to the FBO
    fbo.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch.setShader(defaultShader);

        batch.begin();
        float lightSize = lightOscillate? (4.75f + 0.25f * (float)Math.sin(zAngle) + .2f*MathUtils.random()):5.0f;
        //Draw light 1
        batch.draw(light, 0, 0, lightSize, lightSize);

        //Draw light 2
        batch.draw(light, 2, 2, lightSize, lightSize);

        batch.end();
    fbo.end();

    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    //draw the actual scene
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.setShader(finalShader);
    batch.begin();
    fbo.getColorBufferTexture().bind(1); //this is important! bind the FBO to the 2nd texture unit
    light.bind(0); //we force the binding of a texture on first texture unit to avoid artefacts
                   //this is because our default and ambiant shader dont use multi texturing...
                   //youc can basically bind anything, it doesnt matter
    tilemap.render(batch, dt);
    batch.end();
}
```